# Can't start Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I can't start eclipse 3.6 helios on ubuntu 10.10 after creating dynamic web project running on internal glassfish server.

I can switch workspace and then eclipse starts.

Using workspace with created Java EE project @ GlassFish prevents eclipse to start.

Deleting .metadata/.lock and .metadata/.log doesn't help.

I have stopped all my containers (Tomcat, GlassFish, Jetty).

Restarting PC doesn't help.

Here's what I found in .log file:

```
!SESSION 2011-03-13 13:47:10.068 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish 4 1 2011-03-13 13:47:15.258
!MESSAGE GlassFish: Already Registered: /home/miso/eclipse/plugins/oracle.eclipse.runtime.glassfish_3.1.0.0/glassfish3/glassfish

!ENTRY com.google.gwt.eclipse.core 4 0 2011-03-13 13:47:16.439
!MESSAGE Could not start source viewer server.
!STACK 0
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.jetty.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWTPlugin.start(GWTPlugin.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentType.getDescriber(ContentType.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.readDescription(ContentDescriptionManager.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.getDescriptionFor(ContentDescriptionManager.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContentDescription(File.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.createResource(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.ProjectResourceSetEditImpl.createResource(ProjectResourceSetEditImpl.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandCreateResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.getResource(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper.getOrCreateResource(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.getResource(EditModel.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleStructuralModel.getPrimaryResource(ModuleStructuralModel.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleStructuralModel.prepareProjectModulesIfNecessary(ModuleStructuralModel.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleStructuralModel.getPrimaryRootObject(ModuleStructuralModel.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.StructureEdit.getComponentModelRoot(StructureEdit.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.StructureEdit.getWorkbenchModules(StructureEdit.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.StructureEdit.getComponent(StructureEdit.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.createResource(VirtualComponent.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.initializeResource(VirtualComponent.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.<init>(VirtualComponent.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.<init>(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.createComponent(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.util.ComponentImplManager.createComponent(ComponentImplManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.util.ComponentImplManager.createComponent(ComponentImplManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ComponentCore.createComponent(ComponentCore.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEDeployableFactory.createModules(J2EEDeployableFactory.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate.cacheModules(ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate.findModule(ProjectModuleFactoryDelegate.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModuleFactory.findModule(ModuleFactory.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerUtil.getModule(ServerUtil.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getModules(Server.java:2314)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServerContentProvider.hasChildren(ServerContentProvider.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.hasChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.callNormalHasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$4(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$3.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2082)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.isExpandable(TreeViewer.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2112)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.updatePlus(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2794)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.updatePlus(TreeViewer.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1492)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1383)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator.createPartControl(CommonNavigator.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServersView2.createPartControl(ServersView2.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:4218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: Looks like you've a Glassfish instance running in the background. Do a quick `ps aux` and `kill -9` any running instances.

Comment: I did "ps aux | grep glassfish" and there indeed was some process. I killed it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would nuke your .project file and all associated metadata, uninstall the glassfish plugin, attempt re-import of the project and reinstall the plugin.

You may also consider just running glassfish outside of eclipse and deploying the build binaries with an Ant Script/Maven. I have had nothing but  trouble with those eclipse server adapters

Comment: I can simply create new workspace and move project there but it's tricking me why is eclipse doing this to me :/

Comment: Yes, either a running process or the eclipse-glassfish plugin is the culprit. uninstall the plugin and try once. Also, please don't run servers inside your IDE. Always have it run outside of the IDE and stay trouble-free.

Comment: @Xorty - its probably being passive aggressive, because you are forcing it to start the glassfish server:) But like asgs said its might be that. You may also check your bind address for glassfish. One common cause of this error is a typo in the IP address.(i.e. you are on box 192.168.1.2 and the bind address for glassfish is 192.168.1.3 because it was cut and paste from another machine, if there is already something bound to that address on another box you'll see this message) I have done that with JBoss machines a number of times

Comment: Funny thing is, when I remove glassfish deployed project from workspace, then restart PC, then grep glassfish I found noting running ... I guess I'll just keep using another workspace for glassfish stuff